# Problems compiling a kernel I have modified

Tags: c, linux, makefile, compilation, kernel

I took Linux kernel version 4.9.30, added a new directory /fsac whose files include headers from other directory (/include/fsac) and that is almost all I changed. Trying to compile I get a lot of errors in /kernel/sched/core.c that look like this:

```
kernel/sched/core.c:2326:20: error: invalid storage class for function ‘set_schedstats’

kernel/sched/core.c:2342:19: error: invalid storage class for function ‘setup_schedstats’

(...)
```

Searching on-line I saw that the recommendation was to simply remove the 'static' from the functions. Doing that effectively avoided that errors, but instead I started getting a lot of warnings from objtool like "frame pointer state mismatch" for each of the functions whose static was removed.

I discovered these warnings can be avoided by changing in the configuration file `CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=n`. That worked but even though there is no warning, compilation fails (Error 2).

Hence, I am wondering:

1 - Is the removal of "static" from the offended functions the proper solution?

2 - If so, how do I deal with the objtool warnings? Can those warnings alone constitute a compilation error, or there must be something else?

3 - Do you think I should degrade GCC?

This is the source code of the project: https://github.com/Zildj1an/FSAC_Kernel
This is the compilation log w/o removing the statics: https://github.com/Zildj1an/FSAC_Kernel/blob/master/build_err

I will happily provide any other information you might need.

Cheers.

Comment: Better you also add the compilation warnings here, please.

Comment: `static` functions are functions that are only visible to other functions in the same file. So, if you are using those `static` functions outside the original file (I guess you may be using them in your code) then you gonna get these errors.

Comment: @campescassiano done!!  I am not using functions from core.c

Comment: Are you able to compile the kernel without your modifications?

Answer (score 1):

Problem found, I had a function inside a function... Probably was moved copying something else.